# Django @login_required decorator

Tags: python, django, view, login-required

When writing views, it's obviously a good practice - if not mandatory - to use the @login_required decorator.

BUT - that only checks for authenticates users of

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

What I want to accomplish is to also check that the User exists as a UserProfile.
In my app, for instance, I have some UserProfiles. All have User objects related to them, ofcourse.
but I also have other users which don't have a UserProfile. Such user is my admin user.
I want to make sure that requests come from users who have UserProfiles (and that are authenticated).

Is there a way to change the decorator to support that?
Currently I just wrote my own code to do that:

```
def user_login(request):
  context = context = RequestContext(request)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    try:
      user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
      user_profile = user.userprofile
    except (ObjectDoesNotExist,AttributeError) as e:
      # username and password only prompted for debug purposes.
      error_msg = "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
      print (error_msg)
      # print (request)
      # return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
      return render(request, 'bz/login.html', {'error_msg': error_msg})

    if user and user_profile:
      if user.is_active:
        login(request,user)
        # return HttpResponse("You're now logged in as " + username)
        # return render(request, 'bz/index.html', {})
        return render(request, 'bz/index.html', {'userprofile': user_profile})
        # return HttpResponseRedirect('bz/login.html')
      else:
        error_msg = "Your account is disabled"
        print (error_msg)
        return render(request, 'bz/login.html', {'error_msg': error_msg})
        # return HttpResponse(error_msg)
    else:
      error_msg = "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
      print (error_msg)
      return render(request, 'bz/login.html', {'error_msg': error_msg})
      # return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
  else:
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
      return render(request, 'bz/index.html', {})
    else:
      return render(request, 'bz/login.html', {})
```

Your input would be very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/) decorator to take a function that checks the user profile

e.g.

```
def has_user_profile(user):
    #return a True if one exists, else False

@login_required
@user_passes_test(has_user_profile)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```